# MariaDB installation ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mariadb

I want to install MariaDB 10.1 on a fresh 16.04 server installation but I keep getting this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.1 (= 10.1.20+maria-1~xenial) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have already tried reinstalling Ubuntu as well as pinning the repository but it didn't help at all. I am using the installation instructions from the official website.

Comment: please post the link to the official website

Answer (score 0):

Would any of this help?

```
https://downloads.mariadb.org/
https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/10.1.20/
```

For Ubuntu, here is a better link.  Might be safe to skip #mirror=...

```
https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=jaleco
```

I haven't succeeded in solving this one yet.
(See [Ubuntu 16.04 MariaDB 10.1 installation in Retrograde :D](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868512/ubuntu-16-04-mariadb-10-1-installation-in-retrograde-d))

Comment: If you get to a point where you want to tarball the mysql directories, clean up everything and re-install, this is working so far as the installation. [See, in askubuntu.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/868512/ubuntu-16-04-mariadb-10-1-installation-in-retrograde-d)

Now if anyone has tips on getting the database back from the tarball, I'd appreciate it.