# Ubuntu 16.04 MariaDB 10.1 installation in Retrograde :D

Tags: 16.04, apt, mariadb

Anyone know how to read this scenario?  I upgraded 10.1, it made it 10.0, and made the database inaccessible.  (I have a file backup of the directory)

I cleaned it up, eventually with apt-get purge, renamed /var/lib/MySQL and /etc/MySQL, (m y s q l, ... darn autocorrect!)  Tried it again, and it wants to go to 5.7, even when the repos and mariadb pgp keys are updated.

Here it is ...

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http ://sfo1 .mirrors .digitalocean .com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http ://mirrors .easynews .com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http ://mirrors .easynews .com/linux/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http ://mirrors .easynews .com/linux/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:5 http ://archive .ubuntu .com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.0-5 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7
  mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.0-5 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7
  mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 160 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

(Spaces added in mirrors because askubuntu thinks I am posting links.)

Any idea what's up?  What am I missing?

My friend says it is because Mercury is in retrograde till the 8th.
Very funny, still ... I'd like to try.

Thanks for your time / commiseration

Answer (score 1):

This article helped get mariadb 10.1.20 up and running on 16.04.1, after all that mess.

```
https://www.linuxbabe.com/mariadb/install-mariadb-10-1-ubuntu14-04-15-10
```

I still don't know how to read the murky retrograde :D and how to avoid it in future.

Perhaps now I would be able to use my old database files from the tarball ... tips anyone?

Specifically, from this article, I didn't use the `sudo apt-key adv...` line because I had already done that, and IMPORTANT I *tried* to use aptitude to delete unused files before using Xiao Guoan's steps.  Seems I don't have aptitude :) yet.

Well, some people having this problem are clearly newer than me to this, ... consider running mysqyl_secure_installation right after it.

```
See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysql_secure_installation/
```

I still don't know how to read how the retrograde :) happened.

Thanks... esp., if you'd have any tips

Comment: Did you try using the official MariaDB website?  Downloads Setting up MariaDB Repositories  (https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=osuosl&distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=xenial--ubuntu_xenial&version=10.1)

Comment: Thanks for answering Steve.  

I did try that, and I should have updated this, but see why I was reluctant ▬

Apparently, it had something to do with the `Sonicwall/Firewall` outside the server, believe it or not.   I wish I knew more about this to even ask them to say anything about it here, but it worked once I was told how to avoid that _overpolicing._

Frankly, I still don't know why it went retrograde either, although I am reasonably sure it was not a technical issue or `Mariadb's` fault.

Comment: I will appreciate any pointers about securing the integrity of software update processes ▬ I've practically been away from the 'tech world' since 2003, and not predictable when I will see it again :)

Comment: My apologies, but I have no further advice.